# How to use select * with union ? mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to run this query :

```
SELECT col1 , col2 , table1.*
    FROM
    (SELECT table2.col1 as col1 , table2.col2 as col2 , table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ...
    UNION
    SELECT table3.col1 as col1 , table2.col2 as col2 , table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ...
    )order by table1.col1
```

but I couldn't run it, because I should replace table1.* at ( SELECT col1 , col2 , table1.*) with the table1 columns names .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an alias for the union query.

Something like:

```
SELECT col1 , col2 , talias.*
FROM
(SELECT table2.col1 as col1 , table2.col2 as col2 , table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ...
UNION
SELECT table3.col1 as col1 , table2.col2 as col2 , table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ...
) as talias order by talias.col1
```

Comment: could you give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a mysql here, but try to add table1 in your FROM section and name your subquery

```
SELECT TableUnion.col1 , TableUnion.col2 , table1.*
    FROM
    (SELECT table2.col1 as col1 , table2.col2 as col2 , table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ...
    UNION
    SELECT table3.col1 as col1 , table2.col2 as col2 , table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ...
    ) as TableUnion, table1 order by table1.col1
```